# How to format a cell for date format in excel with openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying create a program that read a .log files, and extract yours information and write a .xlsx file, and i maked this, but when i write the dates informations, the excel interpret as text, and not as date, how can i solve it?

I tried make this:

```
page.cell(line, 2).number_format = '22'
```

after of i maked this:

```
time = contents[12:] # extracts the date in .log file
```

Because of this documentation:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/styles/numbers.html

But not solve to

Comment: StyleIDs are numbers, not strings

Comment: Convert the text, presumably from CSV, to a Python datetime object.

Comment: Excel dates are binary values, not text translated based on a format. Same for numbers. If you want to store dates or numbers in Excel, store the actual Python objects, not their string representation. `number_format` specifies how those binary values will be displayed to the end user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel dates are binary values, not text translated based on a format. Same for numbers. If you want to store dates or numbers in Excel, store the actual Python objects, not their string representation. `number_format`specifies how those binary values will be displayed to the end user

This is shown in the [Using Number Formats](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#using-number-formats) section of the `Simple Usage` doc page:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from openpyxl import Workbook
>>> wb = Workbook()
>>> ws = wb.active
>>> # set date using a Python datetime
>>> ws['A1'] = datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 21)
>>>
>>> ws['A1'].number_format
'yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss'
```

In this code `ws['A1'] = datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 21)` stores a Python datetime object to cell `A1`. Then it specifies that this cell will be displayed using the `yyyy-mm-dd h:mm:ss` format.

A quirk/feature of Excel is that some of the built-in formats are culture-aware. That includes the datetime format `m/d/yyyy h:mm`. Specifying that format will display single-digit months and two-digit years in the user's locale. A user in the US will see `7/21/2010` while a user in any other country will see `21/7/2010`. I'm not sure if `/` is also localized, which means Germans and Russians see `21.7.2010`.

It's also possible to specify built-in formats using their NumberFormatId number, which is where 22 comes from. In the Excel document, the format will appear as a `numFmtId` attribute. In the source code you linked to, the `NumberFormat` class has both a `numFmtId` and a `formatCode` attribute.

Another quirk/feature is that patterns matching a built-in format are replaced by that format's Format ID. Or the format ID takes precedence over the patter, I'm not sure. This means you can't force the US format with `m/d/y h:mm`. Excel will treat this as the built-in short datetime.